# Matching two datasets using different IDs

Tags: r

I have two datasets, one is longitudinal (following individuals over multiple years) and one is cross-sectional. The cross-sectional dataset is compiled from the longitudinal dataset, but uses a randomly generated ID variable which does not allow to track someone across years. I need the panel/longitudinal structure, but the cross-sectional dataset has more variables available than the longitudinal,

The combination of ID-year uniquely identifies each observation, but since the ID values are not the same across the two datasets (they are randomized in cross-sectional so that one cannot track individuals) I cannot match them based on this.

I guess I would need to find a set of variables that uniquely identify each observation, excluding ID, and match based on those. How would I go about ding that in R?

The long dataset looks like so

```
id year y
1  1    10
1  2    20
1  3    30
2  1    15
2  2    20
2  3    5
```

and the cross dataset like so

```
id   year  y   x
912  1     10  1
492  2     20  1
363  3     30  0
789  1     15  1
134  2     25  0
267  3     5   0
```

Now, in actuality the data has 200-300 variables. So I would need a method to find the smallest set of variables that uniquely identifies each observation in the long dataset and then match based on these to the cross-sectional dataset.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there is a unique set of non-id variables that uniquely identifies each observation in the long data set? In the example data there isn't - if we look at `year` and `y` the values are identical in row 2 and row 5. So there is no way to know whether cross-sectional ID `492` corresponds to long ID `1` or `2`.

Comment: You are right! Data in question were made up by me to give and idea of how it looks. Regarding the actual data: I am not sure, but the combination ID-year does uniquely identify. So this would be part of my question. Is there a way in R to find a set of variables that uniquely identify each observation if that is possible at all.

Comment: You can see if `nrow(unique(select(long_data, -id))) < nrow(unique(long_data))`. If there are less rows in the version without the ID column, then you're out of luck. But if they are the same then there is a set of variables uniquely defining an entry. However, I don't understand why you'd bother trying to find a minimal set of uniquely identifying variables. It will probably be more work to find such a set then to just match on all the non-ID variables.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, finding the minimal set is not actually necessary for me. Just thought matching on all variables except ID would be too big a task for my laptop. The longitudinal data has almost 200k observations and 200+ variables.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the only way to find a minimal set is going to be to try different subsets of columns, and there are 200! of those. (Though maybe I'm misunderstanding... it's hard to tell the difference between your longitudinal and cross-sectional data from the example given.)

Comment: The difference between them is that in the cross-sectional the IDs are random and you cannot easily track an individual over multiple years. In the longitudinal the IDs are the same for a given individual if he is observed for multiple years. The cross-sectional, however, has more variables per observation (some that I need). For my purposes I need to be able to observe individuals over multiple years, but I also need some variables only available in the cross-sectional. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: That does. The "longitudinal" vs "cross-sectional" made me think the structure was more different, but your above comment clears that up.